# How to compute voltage limits in n-MOS transistor?

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I have come across two different ways of computing the \$V_d\$:

- In the first one, the DC bias point is considered to not be affected by AC, so by superposition, $$V_d = V_{d;V_{AC}=0} + V_{d;V_{DC}=0} $$, where $$ V_{d;V_{AC}=0} = V_{dd} - I_{d;DC}\times R_d$$ and $$ V_{d;V_{DC}=0} =  -2k(V_{gs}-V_{t}) \times V_{gs; {AC}}\times R_d $$
- In the second one, first the maximum and minimum values of the sensor's voltage is computed, and then the maximum and minimum \$V_d's\$ are computed as $$ V_{d} = V_{dd} - I_{d;DC}\times R_d$$, where $$I_{d;DC}= k(V_{gs}-V_{t})^2$$

Both methods give slightly different results. Which is more correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct but for different conditions.  the first is linear gain with AC and DC while The second is used as a switch with the resistance depending on the difference between the Vgs and the threshold, Vt=Vgs(th)
Normally as a switch Vgs >= 2.5Vt for low RdsOn

Comment: Thank you. So, how do I know when to use each method if it is not specified in the problem statement?

Comment: You can tell by Vgs & Vds if it is low , then Vgs is >2Vt, then it  is starting as a DC switch with RdsOn being the main result